# In C# change visio Shape Position

Tags: c#, position, visio, shapes

Hi im working with c# where i insert a axDrawingControl for Visio...

So now my question, if i insert a visio shape

```
currentPage.Drop(positionStencil.Masters["Pos1"], 0.8, 4.2);
```

How can i change the Position of the shape now?

Thx for you help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the **PinX** and **PinY** cells. Typically you'll set these to the center of the new location you want to shape to appear.

```
var shape = currentPage.Drop(...);
shape.CellsU["PinX"].Formula = "2";
shape.CellsU["PinY"].Formula = "2";
```

(The sample above is for C# in Visual Studio 2010, the code will look a little less clean in Visual Studio 2008)

Just to be complete: You should read up on the **LocPinX** and **LocPinY** cells because these affect how PinX and PinY are interpreted. It shouldn't have any impact on your scenario thought.

If you have to do this for a number of shapes instead of just one, it is more efficient to use the **SetFormulas** method (available on the **Page** and **Shape** object depending on your needs).